# XHP with Regex for link Replacement

Tags: php, regex, hacklang, xhp

I am trying to implement a simple function that given a text input, returns the text modified with `xhp_a` when a link is detected, within a paragraph `xhp_p`.

Consider this class

```
class Urlifier {

    protected static $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";


    public static function convertParagraphWithLink(?string $input):xhp_p{
        if (!$input)
            return <p></p>;
        else
        {
            if (preg_match(self::$reg_exUrl,$input,$url_match)) //match found
            {
                return <p>{preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="'.$url_match[0].'>'.$url_match[0].'</a>', $input)}<p>;
            }else{//no link inside
                <p>{$input}</p>
            }
        }
}
```

The problem here is that `xhp` escapes `html` and links are not shown as expected. I suppose that this happens because a do not create a dom hierarchy as expected (with `appendChild` method for example) and thus everything `regex` replaces is a string.

So my other approach to this problem was to use `preg_match_callback` with a callback function that would create `xhp_a` and add to hierarchy under `xhp_p` but that did not work either.

Am i wrong somewhere ? If not would there by any security risk / bigger overhead by just finding and replacing on load the html on client side instead of server ?

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

Since XHP maintains object hierarchy that maps to DOM, simply replacing parts of a string won't create any new objects. To manipulate XHP objects corresponding methods should be used, e.g. `appendChild`.

Here's an example of how what you need can be achieved with XHP manipulation.

```
class Urlifier {

  public static function convertParagraphWithLink(
    ?string $input,
  ): xhp_p {
    $url_pattern = re"/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
    if (HH\Lib\Str\is_empty($input)) {
      return <p/>;
    }
    $input = $input as nonnull;
    // Extract links
    $link_matches = HH\Lib\Regex\every_match($input, $url_pattern);
    $links = HH\Lib\Vec\map($link_matches, $m ==> $m[0]);
    $a_elements = HH\Lib\Vec\map($links, $link ==> <a href={$link}>{$link}</a>);
    // Extract all pieces between matches
    $texts = HH\Lib\Regex\split($input, $url_pattern);
    $p_elements = HH\Lib\Vec\map($texts, $text ==> <p>{$text}</p>);
    
    // Merge texts and links
    $pairs = HH\Lib\Vec\zip($p_elements, $a_elements);
    $elements = HH\Lib\Vec\flatten($pairs);
    
    // Because there's one more p element than a element, append last p
    $elements[] = HH\Lib\C\last($p_elements);

    $result = <p/>;
    $result->appendChild($elements);
    
    return $result;
  }
```

Comment: Hopefully you figured something sooner and wasn't blocked for 6 years :D 
But in case someone encounters this question, it might be useful to have an answer